# How to use restricted mixin to an interface with implementation of that interface at same time in dart?

Tags: dart, oop, interface, mixins

What I have:

1. Interface (InterfaceA) with a method that must be overridden.
2. Restricted to interface mixin (MixinB) with a method that I want to use without overriding.
3. Class (ClassC) with implementation of interface and usage of mixin.

Question:
Is it possible to use restricted mixin to interface with implementation of that interface at the same time?

Code below is an example and shows how I ideally want to use mixin and interface

```dart
abstract class InterfaceA {
  int getValue();
}

mixin MixinB on InterfaceA {
  int getPreValue(int i) => i;
}

// Error:
// 'Object' doesn't implement 'InterfaceA' so it can't be used with 'MixinB'.
class ClassC with MixinB implements InterfaceA {
  @override
  getValue() => getPreValue(2);
}
```

Comment: In your example, you could do `class C extends InterfaceA with MixinB`.  instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mixin doesn't *need* to be used on a class of type `InterfaceA`.
You could declare it as

```dart
mixin MixinB implements InterfaceA {
  in getPrevAlue(int i) => i;
}
```

instead. Then using the mixin will require the mixin application class to implement `InterfaceA`, because the mixin doesn't provide the implementation, but the it can do so before or after mixing in the mixin.
Then your code would just be:

```dart
class ClassC with MixinB { // no need for `implements InterfaceA`
  @override
  getValue() => getPreValue(2);
}
```

Only use an `on` requirement on a mixin if you need to *call* a super-interface member on the `on` type(s) using `super.memberName`. Otherwise just use `implements` to ensure that the resulting object will implement that interface. You can still do normal virtual calls on the interface.

Example:

```dart
abstract class MyInterface {
  int get foo;
}
mixin MyMixin implements MyInterface {
  int get bar => this.foo; // Valid!
}
class MyClass with MyMixin {
  @override
  int get foo => 42;
  int useIt() => this.bar; // returns 42
}
```